# How to bind a django form to an object instance

Tags: python, django

I come from DRF background so please already assume that I might be getting something wildly wrong here. I am trying to use [Django Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#django-s-role-in-forms) as a sort of proxy for DRF serializers. As in, when I fetch an object, I can quickly render it back, and I can of course accept POST requests and store them. What I can't seem to find is how do I use my object instances to process them with forms.

Here's my form:

```py
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('name', 'profile_pic')
```

The actual model:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

My view:

```py
def get_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # update the model
        profile = request.user.userprofile
        form = ProfileForm(model_to_dict(profile))
        if not form.is_valid():
            form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

So, in my view (which is a GET view), I'm doing something like this:

```py
from django.forms import model_to_dict
profile = request.user.userprofile
form = ProfileForm(model_to_dict(profile))
return render(..., form)
```

Is this even the right approach? Besides, the problem is that my form doesn't seem to handle the `profile_pic` field properly (i.e. the `img src` field in the from html is just `__`).

Ideally I would want to build the form from the object instance itself, but that also doesn't work.

`form = ProfileForm(instance = profile)` is  `bound`, but not `valid`

`form = ProfileForm(UserProfile.objects.all()[0])` is `bound`, and I can access data items through `form.data.<fields>`, but as soon as do `form.is_valid()`, I get:

> AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'

UPDATE: `form = ProfileForm(request.<GET/POST>, instance=profile)` is actually `bound` but not `valid` with the error that field `name` is required, even though `profile.name` is indeed valid `CharField`.

So how can I take my object, then bind it to a form, and then return it to be rendered properly. Imgine this is a user profile that I render, but also let the user update it whenever they want. What is the Django way of doing it? (I come from DRF background.)

Most of the SO answers that I have found almost always initialize the form with `request.POST` which I don't need.

EDIT: **My use case**, I have an endpoint `/profile` which, when requested as `GET`, should return a profile (with all the info that their `UserProfile` object holds but the user can also edit any of the fields that they want to. Say they have edited a field, they can simply hit update, which would then submit the form. On the backend, there profile would get updated, and they would get served the latest profile details. Of course, I can do it by rendering a from using a template, but I instead wanted to use the form which is already there. As I mentioned `model_to_dict` approach kind of serves this point to some extent, except it breaks for images... so I thought there might be a solution.

Comment: A form is `bound` if it also receives data, so `ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)`. After all the form only saves when it receives data, other than the one from the instance.

Comment: But my above line is sitting in a GET view :/

Comment: @DaveIdito then `ProfileForm(request.GET, instance=profile)`. Anyway a form does not need to be bound to be rendered. `ProfileForm(instance=profile)` is enough to render the form to update the given instance (the values from the start would be of the instance provided). See [Bound and unbound form instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances) in the documentation. **Note:** If this view is updating the profile instance it is best to do the update in a POST method.

Comment: It makes no sense to work with a GET request, a GET request is supposed to have *no* side-effects, so it should *not* update anything.

Comment: @Daveldito: see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand that I might be crossing conventions here, but I just wanted to (mis)use forms so I won't have manually filter all fields and pass it to the form in my template in my use case (of a profile that can be updated anytime) i.e. it's effectively a form.

Comment: @DaveIdito you say `form = ProfileForm(request.<GET/POST>, instance=profile)` is not bound? How do you check that? What does `print(form.is_bound)` give? Also your comment above is very unclear.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry I was relying on the template (only for this one). I debugged and it is indeed bound. But not valid. I will try to re-edit the question appropriately and hopefully clarify things further.

Comment: @DaveIdito: I think it might help if you explain *what* you aim to do (and not only *how*). Right now your question is quite confusing, since you only are currently *constructing* a form with data from an instance, but you are not *processing* the data entered in the form when it is submitted.

Comment: @DaveIdito I believe you are confused in some manner. The form should be bound once the user **submits** it, if you just want to display a form to the user and allow them to update some instance `ProfileForm(instance=profile)` is enough for your needs also as Willem states above please clarify properly. Add your complete view (or at least a shortened version of it which is complete on its own) and your template to the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat please let me know if it is clear now. Because if it is not, then I guess I would remove the question and re-consider the whole approach; maybe I am off by far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your view you make some mistakes which simply make using the forms difficult.  Firstly if you want to update a form you should instantiate the form with the model  instance so instead of `form = ProfileForm(model_to_dict(profile))` it should be `form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)`.

Also right after this line you write:

```
if not form.is_valid():
    form = ProfileForm()
```

Why check `is_valid` on a form that is not bound?

Your view should ideally look something like:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect


@login_required
def get_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: @DaveIdito that is not supposed to be bound, what you see is correct. A bound form is a form which is passed the users input. When you write `ProfileForm(instance=profile)` that is not related to the users input in any way, it can simply be said to be initial data.

Comment: But isn't that what you did in the answer i.e. `form=ProfileForm(instance=profile)` and it works there?! My question is that if it is not bound in the shell (and you say it shouldn't be), then why would `is_valid` work in the view?

Comment: @DaveIdito I have written `form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)` just before calling `is_valid` (this is the case for the POST request).